# SQLite via Sqlite.NET: What is the default Timeout for CRUD operations, how to change it?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, android-sqlite, sqlite-net

What is the default timeout for CRUD operations in SQLite via Sqlite.NET?

Is it possible to change the default timeout for CRUD operations via either Sqlite.NET or SQLite directly?

I cannot find any information via search engines.

https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

https://www.sqlite.org/index.html

Comment: is there a specific reason you're asking this, or just curiosity?  I've written dozens of mobile apps with sqlite and never encountered a timeout issue.

Comment: We have apps that are blocked. That is why I want to know the timeout. Regardless, the timeout should be documented publicly.